# unmet dependecies problem

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, xinerama

When I try to install *libxinerama-dev*, I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxinerama-dev : Depends: libxinerama1 (= 2:1.1.3-1) but 2:1.1.3-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have followed [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/333661) but with no luck... still the same error..

this is my *source.list*:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

and *source.list.d/**:

```
# deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/nitro/ubuntu trusty main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
# deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/nitro/ubuntu trusty main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
```

I really dont know what to do it has been a week now..

Also, I have tried to download *2:1.1.3-1+b1* version, the installation went well but when I check the version it remain the same.. (*2:1.1.3-1*)

EDIT:
This is the *uname -a* output:

```
3.16.0-37-generic #51~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 6 15:23:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you tried getting a list of held packages with 

dpkg --get-selections | grep hold

and manually installing them?

Comment: @DJINDISGUISE there is no held packages :\

Comment: hrrrmmmmm, Well you have a dependencise problem and your repos are finding the wrong version, take a look here and try and locate the installation files for your required version (2:1.1.3-1) and install with sudo dpk -i

ALSO, some details like which version of Ubuntu, 32/64bit would be useful in helping solve this problem. Could you add them o your original post please?

Comment: @DJINDISGUISE I have added it now :) i am now trying to install it

Comment: I'm going to answer here because I was a derp and messed up this thread. 

Do yes go ahead and download the stable release of the  appropriate version of the package you need. Pop open a terminal and move to the download directory then,

sudo dpkg -i  <Package>.deb

Comment: what was the format of your download?

Comment: My bad, forgot to enable javascript :) I got [this error](http://pastebin.com/0P9aw8LJ)

Comment: Scratch that Try: apt-get clean,  apt-get update, apt-get  upgrade, apt-get install -f THEN  dpkg --configure -a. I know that seems like a lot but it's only for the sake of being thorough

Comment: Thanks!! post that in the solution so I can mark it as solved! :)
(Include the previous comment too!)

Comment: also, awesome cause this will be my first "Answered" question on this Stack Exchange! :D thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxinerama) the stable release of the appropriate version of the package you need. Pop open a terminal and move to the download directory then:

```
sudo dpkg -i <Package>.deb
```

Not working? Then do the following:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -f
dpkg --configure -a.
```

I know that seems like a lot but it's only for the sake of being thorough. 
After that, try to install it again using `dpkg`.

Comment: I edited your solution a little bit :) Thanks!

Comment: @NaorHadar that's a massive edit - if that's your contribution, consider adding an answer of your own.

Comment: I mean it's all stuff from our conversation I n the comments I don't think It's that big a  deal

Comment: @muru He just forgot to add the previous comment so I added it for him, also, I edited the solution a little bit so anyone seeing this will have no problem solving it. That is not my answer so the credit goes to him :)

Comment: tyty I'll work on being more detailed in my answers!